# Create an EXE or setup file in .NET Windows application which can use SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have been working on a C# windows application with SQL Server 2005, and now I need to deploy it to other system.

I created a setup file using setup an deployment filling all the prerequisite but as I deploy it on another computer error keeps popping up saying it can't open connection.

I am thinking my problem here is in deployed project database is missing.

Now my question is how can I use this database and I have connection string that work only in my system so I need to change this connection string too.

How can I do that?

Please help me tackle my problem...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you using sql compact or sql ? if it is sql compact, you can add the file to you project and join it to you project and deploy it, if it is SQL you need to have an Public WAN SQL server so you app can access it thru internet.

Comment: i am using sql. but can you help me how  can i deploy sql compact as well as sql

Comment: sql compact is just like sql, but in a file. Just config your OleDB connection and add an sql compact database file to you project and create an DataBound to it.